# Get the value timestamp when grouping by time in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I am trying to get the MAX/MIN values of an interval of time, and I would like to get the correspond timestamp of the value.

If I run: `SELECT max(value) FROM data WHERE time > 1549034249000000000 and time < 1550157449000000000 GROUP BY time(10s)`

I am receiving the timestamp of the range beginning instead of the max(value) timestamp.

What alternatives could there be for receiving the max(value) of an interval and his timestamp?

In SQL is possible to execute a query like: `SELECT value DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY time ORDER BY variableName DESC) AS Rank FROM tableName` Is not possible to run something like that in InfluxDB?

Answer (score 1):

Yout can not. When you use group by you get ever the beginning timestamp of the group by.

The alternative is not to use group by.

Comment: Yes, but how can I do that without doing as querys as time intervals there are? Because if I have 500 intervals, I have to run 500 querys, I dont think it is the best way to do that.